# PHP unable to assign values in array

Tags: php, arrays, syntax-error

I am unable to get this right! I am simply trying to create an array of names `$json` from mysql table data and later return this data as json using this code:

```
json_encode($json)
```

Getting syntax error in the 5th line in the following code where the `$json` array is assigned values from the database inside the loop.

```
$sql = "select * from mytable";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$json = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
     $json[] = ['id'=>$row['id'], 'text'=>$row['title']];
}
```

I tried replacing the single quotes with double quotes.. but no success..

having a bad day :-(

Comment: did you try to execute your code or is that syntax error just from your IDE?

Comment: just from the ide...

Comment: then refer to the answer below bt AbraCadaver, it will fix your issue, although your code as it appears right now is also correct and will execute. It is just your IDE which picks this up as a syntax error.

Comment: What PHP version are you using?

Comment: I am using PHP Ver 5.5.12

Comment: So it's just the IDE.  See if there is an update for it or way to have it recognize newer PHP syntax.

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 3):

Most likely the `[]` syntax, you need to use `array()` instead for PHP < 5.4.0:

```
$json[] = array('id'=>$row['id'], 'text'=>$row['title']);
```

But it could be much easier if you change the query to select only the columns needed AS the name needed and use `fetch_all()`:

```
$sql = "select id, title AS text from mytable";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);    
$json = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

If it's just the IDE, see if there is an update for it or way to have it recognize newer PHP syntax.

Comment: Good answer. Still adds value even if the array syntax was not root cause. (though suppose it was even if false err from IDE?).